# ASP.NET MVC2 - Can I use session to store user login status

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 and I need to save user login status to indicate if he is logged in and show some private data.

What I did was just add UserID in session `Session.Add("UserID", user.ID.ToString());` and then redirected to `user` page that is getting UserID `string userID = Session["UserID"].ToString();` and if it exists pull out data from DB and show it to user.

As far as I know Session data is stored on server-side so my first thought is that it is pretty safe to use this method. However I checked in Chrome and it is creating some kind of cookie which makes me doubt.

Can someone tell me if this method is safe?

Comment: The answer below is correct, although unless you are using a secure protocol (SSL), it may be possible for someone to hijack a logged-in session.  A great security eBook here: http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/12/free-ebook-owasp-top-10-for-net.html (part 9 is probably the bit related to your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie that is being created (a) is encrypted and (b) does not contain the actual data, but rather a session identifier used to retrieve the proper session for the thread handling the request.  It's a perfectly reasonable and secure way to save the data.  I believe that the cookie is HttpOnly by default (you should verify this) and shouldn't be exposed to scripts in the browser.  If it isn't HttpOnly, you should configure it to be so (using the httpCookies directive) - best practice would dictate that cookies should be HttpOnly unless specifically required for use by the client directly.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just created better way of doing it by using ActionFilterAttribute, but still using session for checking.

Answer (score 0):

ASP .NET MVC maintains session state by providing the client with a unique key (session id) when the session begins, that is stored in an HTTP cookie. Session id is sent to the server on each request.

You can set

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState cookieless="true" />
</system.web>
```

then session id would be passed in url, that is less secure

Answer (score 0):

You can encript cookie. It is perfectly ok by the way. For example when using Federated Authentication your SAML(or other) token is stored in encripted cookie.

Even if someone intercepts your cookie, he cant read it. To prevent data corruption - sign them. Also you can add cookie owner URI to it and validate it.

Quite same as tvanfosson opinion. Just noticed it=) But will post anyway.